# how to suppress messagebox popups while running batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a little script that takes an sql dump, transforms it to xml, then transforms the xml to an html page, then finally fop's it to a pdf

I have written a batch file, but I consistently get popup messageboxes telling me what is happening through each step.

How would you go about suppressing these message boxes?

My batch is simply:

```
@echo off

transform data_files\sql_dump data_files\sql_to_xml transformed_files\sql_dump_to_xml
transform transformed_files\sql_dump_to_xml data_files\convert_to_html_amt transformed_files\converted_to_html_amount html
transform transformed_files\sql_dump_to_xml data_files\convert_to_html_date transformed_files\converted_to_html_date html
transform transformed_files\sql_dump_to_xml data_files\convert_to_html_sperson transformed_files\converted_to_html_salesperson html
transform transformed_files\sql_dump_to_xml data_files\convert_to_fo transformed_files\converted_to_fo fo
fop transformed_files\converted_to_fo.fo transformed_files\converted.png
fop transformed_files\converted_to_fo.fo transformed_files\converted.pdf
fop transformed_files\converted_to_fo.fo transformed_files\converted.rtf
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

batch files do not issue any messageboxes on their own.

try to read documentation for your `transform` and `fop` tools, maybe they need a special flag to be quiet.

usually commandline tools show their supported switches when ran like `fop -h` or `fop -?` or `fop /?` or `fop --help`

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense, had to separate the two.
Dohhh.